# A bug when creating parameters for request.get

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, parameters, request

I'm iterating this website and try to scrape the links of news articles.
https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China%20COVID-19#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%20COVID-19&gsc.page=1

First, I need to get the links of the pages, so I used this code:

```
def scrape(url):
    user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    request = 0
    params = {
        'q': 'China%20COVID-19',
        'gsc.tab': '0',
        'gsc.q': 'China%20COVID-19',
    }
    pagelinks = []
    
    myarticle = []
    for page_no in range(1,3):
        try:# to avoid "No connection adapters were found for" error
            params['gsc.page'] = page_no
            response = requests.get(url=url,
                                    headers=user_agent,
                                    params=params) 
            print(response.request.url)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

```
scrape('https://www.usnews.com/search/')
```

However, the results are not correct:

```
https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China%252520COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%252520COVID-19&gsc.page=1
https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China%252520COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%252520COVID-19&gsc.page=2
```

The expected results should like this:

```
https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China%20COVID-19#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%20COVID-19&gsc.page=1
https://www.usnews.com/search?q=China%20COVID-19#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China%20COVID-19&gsc.page=2
```

Could someone help me solve this bug? I'd appreciate that very much!

Comment: I don't know anything about `requests`, but should your params be unencoded: `'q': 'China COVID-19'` ie an actual space instead of a space encoded as `%20`?

Answer (score 1):

If you open up in a browser the URLs that you get, you'll see that the search string is `China%2520COVID-19`, and not `China COVID-19`, as you expect.

The `%20` that you see in the query string is a `urlencoded` space character. See [percent-encoding on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding). If you `urldecode` `China%2520COVID-19`, you'll get `China%20COVID-19`, and by this I get that `%25` is the encoded percent character.

Probably `requests` already `urlencodes` your query string values, so you don't need to. What you could change for it to work is to use the decoded values, e.g. spaces () instead of `%20`.

```py
    params = {
        'q': 'China COVID-19',
        'gsc.tab': '0',
        'gsc.q': 'China COVID-19',
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't lead to the expected results. Copying the URLs into the browser always shows the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Searching in the browser results in 'hashed' URLs (`https://www.usnews.com/search#...`), you need to build the URL yourself.
Passing parameters to requests via `requests.get(..., params=params)` creates a regular query string (`https://www.usnews.com/search?...`) that leads to wrong pages (always the first).

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode, unquote

def scrape(url):
    user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    request = 0
    url = 'https://www.usnews.com/search'
    params = {
        'q': 'China COVID-19',
        'gsc.tab': '0',
        'gsc.q': 'China COVID-19'
    }
    pagelinks = []
    myarticle = []

    for page_no in range(1,4):
        params['gsc.page'] = page_no
        _url = '%s#%s' % (url, urlencode(params))

        try:# to avoid "No connection adapters were found for" error
            response = requests.get(url=_url,
                                    headers=user_agent)
            print(_url, '>>', _url == unquote(response.request.url))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

scrape('https://www.usnews.com/search/')
```

Output:

```
https://www.usnews.com/search#q=China+COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China+COVID-19&gsc.page=1 >> True
https://www.usnews.com/search#q=China+COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China+COVID-19&gsc.page=2 >> True
https://www.usnews.com/search#q=China+COVID-19&gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=China+COVID-19&gsc.page=3 >> True
```

Comment: Thanks! But the last answer doesn't do anything about the hashtag in the urls, it still returns correct urls (without #, but the same page as with #)

Comment: @Yue Peng: I just posted this, because the other answer doesnt work for me. Copying the URLs into the browser always shows the first page.

Comment: You're right! Thank you for noticing! I'm wondering could you parse the URLs that you get? Because I need to scrape the article links from the overall links.

Comment: Something like:  
                `soup_page = bs(response, 'html.parser') 
                #select all the articles for a single page:
                containers = soup_page.findAll("div", {'class': 'usn-site-search-item-container'})
                #scrape the links of the articles:
                for i in containers:
                    url = i.find('a')
                    pagelinks.append(url.get('href'))
                print(pagelinks)`

Comment: @Yue Peng: The search results are loaded via Javascript, requests-library is not able to do that. Even in the browser's source code there are no search results (just in the DOM).

Comment: also looks like it's calling a google search to pull in the results/articles (I'm assuming thats why you see gsc = google search console)